# Multiline python code execution in terminal (Windows)

Tags: python, shell

As the question states, I would like to know how to execute arbitrary python code in a windows terminal (or Anaconda Prompt). Please note that I am on Windows. In general, terminal execution is something like:

```
>>python -c "print('Some Text to Print')"
```

But what happens if I have multiple lines with indents and indent-indents. Here is an example of things I have tried (please note that I am forcing two lines here in some way, the solution "for i in range(10): print(i)" is not appropriate to the question since this only has one line of python code):

```
>>python -c "for i in range(10):;    print(i)"
>>python -c "for i in range(10):\nprint(i)"
>>python -c "for i in range(10):\n    print(i)"
>>python -c "for i in range(10):\n\tprint(i)"
```

Now clearly I can do this:

```
>>python -c "exec('for i in range(10):\n\tprint(i)')"
```

and this solution works. But this solution feels wrong. Is there a more pythonic way? In particular, why do the newline and tab characters work for "exec()" but not for "python -c"?

Comment: Just for clarity, you specifically want the whole thing on the command line and not in a script. Right? And you can't just use WSL to get a proper shell?

Comment: Yes, that is the objective. If I write the text to a file that would defeat the point.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried with ^ ?
In this case if you will not be careful with spaces, you will obtain an *IndentationError: unexpected inden*

```
python -c ^
More? "for i in range(2): ^
More?   print(i)"
```

**[EDIT]**

There are also another way:

```
python -c ^
More? "for i in range(2):^ print(i)"
0
1
```

^ is the EOL character used as the new line character in most other non-Unix operating systems, including Microsoft Windows and Symbian OS.

Comment: That does indeed work. Nice. But why is that not equivalent to "\n\t"? Why doesn't the "\n\t" work?

Comment: @BobbyOcean if I correctly understood, the reason is the EOL character in windows. Windows uses ^ as EOL, so probably "windows" parses the string and than "feed" python.

Comment: The above example seems to simply remove the "^" and proceed with the code all on the same line. Something more complicated fails, "def f(x):^    x=x+1^    return x^print(f(8))".

Comment: @BobbyOcean I  just wanted to show how also inside the string the newline is ^ not \n .

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
> echo "for i in range(2):
>>     print(i)
>> " | python
0
1
```

Comment: This does not appear to work. I do not believe windows supports piping. Also the enter-key appears to execute each line immediately unless you place a ^ at the end.

Comment: @BobbyOcean it's a real example, so believe it

Comment: I wasn't using "not believe" in a literally sense, but in a conversational sense. Let me clarify and be more precise; I attempted your command on windows command prompt and it did not work. In general, windows seems confused by the symbol "|" and appears to simply execute the command proceeding it (almost like an "or" instead of a "pipe"). The windows program "echo" also does auto start another line when a " is used. Instead it immediately executes. The combination of these observations leads me to believe you did not test this on windows.

Comment: @BobbyOcean you probably need powershell

Comment: @BobbyOcean I copied and pasted the command and output, it's not something made up

Comment: yes, I was not using powershell. I was using anaconda prompt and/or cmd. In any case, I do agree that this works, but this doesn't quite answer the question at hand. Why does "\n" fail? Why does exec() behave differently than "python -c". BTW, it appears that starting a " and then pressing enter to produce another line for input, is a special feature of powershell; in other words, you don't need to use echo and can use "python -c".